# Reading properties file in Spring

Tags: java, spring, properties

I was going through Spring tutorials and came across the two ways to read properties from a property file i.e. using `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` and `ResourceBundleMessageSource`.

But i didn't get the difference between these two. In which case one is advantageous over other?

Answer (score 3):

`ResourceBundleMessageSource` is for localized messages to be displayed in application. [Spring documentation on Localization](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#context-functionality-messagesource).

`PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` is used for application configuration. Usually for filling in configuration placeholders `${something}` in application context files. [Spring example of placeholders](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-placeholderconfigurer).